# Static member/ methods and Global scope

Tags: java, jvm, global, static-methods

In Java , there is no Global scope.
then how are the Static members are stored ?

Comment: it's stored in perm gen. Btw details can be found by Googling it. Its fact try it out.

Comment: Please share if you have any links on this topic !

Comment: static fields are stored on the heap like any other object.  You can see these special object in a heap dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static methods (in fact all methods) are stored in the PermGen/metaspace and static fields are stored in a special object for each class on the heap, since they are part of the reflection data (class related data, not instance related).

If your static variable is a reference to an object that object itself is stored in the normal sections of the heap (young/old generation or survivor space). Those objects (unless they are interal objects like classes etc.) are not stored in PermGen space.

Comment: Method code is stored in the PermGen/Metaspace, but static fields are stored in a special object for each class on the heap.  When you do a  heap dump you can see these special objects with a field for each static field.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me Peter. Edited the answer accordingly.